# Dictionary not updating if key and value are not unique

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Im new to python and Im creating this gambling game where a user will have the choice to bet on symbols that will be generated (eventually- haven't gotten there yet). Im creating a dictionary to hold my data for how much the user is betting (the value) and the number corresponding to the symbol they are betting on (the key). Each player has the option to place more than 1 bet per turn. I am running into a problem where if two different players input the same bet&symbol combination (for example $10 on 1 (Crown)) then the dictionary wont update to contain 2 separate entries of 1:10, it will only have one entry of 1:10. This is what Im working with right now

```
def getPlayers():

    print("Hello and Welcome to the Crown and Anchor Game")
    num = int(input('Please enter the number of people playing today: ')) # takes the number of people who are playing from the user
    scoreInit = [] # creating an empty list for the players inital score of 10

    for i in range(num): # for loop to append the inital score of 10 to the empty list scoerInit for the amount of players input 
        scoreInit += i * [10]

    return scoreInit # returns the list of inital scores for the amount of players playing


def collectBets(balance):
    bets = {}
    index = 0
    for i in balance:
        index += 1
        print('Player %d, what would you like to do this round?'  % (index))
        print('1: Bet on a symbol')
        print('2: Skip this round')
        userOpt = int(input('Please enter 1 or 2 depending on your choice: ')) # assigning what the user inputs as the variable 'usesrOpt'
        if userOpt == 1: # if user decides to bet:
            betTimes = int(input('How many times would you like to bet this round?: '))
            for a in range(betTimes):
                betAmount = int(input('Enter the amount you would like to bet this round: $1, $2, $5, or $10: '))
                symbol = int(input('Enter the number corresponding to the symbol you would like to bet on\n' # asking user what symbol they want to bet on - assigning it to a variable
                                       '1: Crown\n'
                                       '2: Anchor\n'
                                       '3: Heart\n'
                                       '4: Diamond\n'
                                       '5: Club\n'
                                       '6: Spade\n'
                                       ))                       

            bets.update({symbol:betAmount})


print(bets)

def main():
    balance1 = getPlayers()
    collectBets(balance1)

main()
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Give a [mcve] with desired output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to think of a Python Dictionary as "an un ordered set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary)." https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

With that being said, whenever user A chooses 10, and then user B chooses 10; user A choice is literally being overwritten by user B's choice. A single dictionary can only hold 10 once as a key. In order to resolve your solution you'll have to use some other data structures. The key within a dictionary should be unique.

A solution to your problem could be to use different levels of dictionaries. You could have a dictionary of player names that holds a dictionary of their value, and their symbol. However, your player names would have to be unique, otherwise you would run into the same issue.